# Django 1.7 - Cannot find tutorials

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I have been searching the net for any references or tutorials for learning Django. Since I'm going to learn it, it makes sense that I learn the newest(releases) version (1.7). However, all the tutorials that I can find (Tango with Django & others), seem to be teaching previous versions(1.5). I wanted to know

1) Are there any good quality guides available for the more recent versions ?
2) Is there a considerable basic difference in the versions of django, that would render the older tutorials completely useless for the more recent versions ?

I understand that the documentation is really good. I did its tutorial. It was wonderful. I just wanted more exposure through other good - quality tutorials (that pertain to the 1.7 version ) before jumping into the documentations.

Comment: Django is one of the best documented frameworks out there, I would say read again the official documentation, once you grasp the idea you move to more advanced stuff even with reading older versions of Django (for your level, changes in django are minor between releases).

Comment: @petkostas Do you recommend that I switch to older (~1.5) versions of django, learn from the tutorials and documentations, and then come back to the newer version, and understand the changes in workflow(if any) ?

Comment: 1.7 has not yet been officially released and there are third party apps that don't work that well with it yet, 1.6 is stable and supported by most 3rd party apps, since you are a beginner I would strongly advice for 1.6 version, changes in the flow of 1.7 are not important for you at this moment, once you grasp the concept then you will be able to understand the 1.7 changes (which are really nice).

Comment: @petkostas I have followed the official tutorial as well as gone through quite a lot of documentation. Even though I do now understand some things, I am having problems in putting things together. So, a good tutorial would be wonderful as that would help me at least get in the flow. Tango with Django is for Django-v1.5. So do you know of any tutorials for v1.6 ? Also, if there isn't much difference in v1.5 / v1.6, should I just go with tango with django as is ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) is up-to-date with the release version:

> This tutorial is written for Django 1.7 and Python 3.2 or later. If
>   the Django version doesn’t match, you can refer to the tutorial for
>   your version of Django by using the version switcher at the bottom
>   right corner of this page, or update Django to the newest version.

Also, since the biggest change in 1.7 is `migrations`, you should probably take some extra time and study the [docs on migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/).

As a side note, 1.7 is in beta currently. You should probably start out with the latest stable version, which is 1.6.5.

Another pretty important note is that [Django 1.7 requires Python 2.7 or above](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#python-compatibility).

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent looking tutorial which would be a great followup to the official Django documentation.

http://souldeux.com/blog/django-note-app-tutorial-part-1-layout-file-structure/

http://arunrocks.com/recreating-the-building-a-blog-in-django-screencast/ also looks good, but is going to make you work a little harder to follow along.

Lastly, https://realpython.com/ has paid tutorials, which are well worth the money in my opinion. These tutorials are more advanced though. So I would recommend doing the first three and trying to build a simple app on your own before you start these.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just getting started with Django, I highly recommend [the Django Girl tutorial](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/).  It takes small steps and explained things better than other tutorials I did, including the Django Project's tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/) are pretty good. After you get the basics on django you can try [the two scoops of django book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098146730X). This book has a ton of useful info and even if it was written for django 1.6 most of the information is still relevant.
You can use their [project template for django 1.7](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) that already has preinstalled the basic apps you should need and a structure that will allow you to ease the building of your project.

I have to check [Obey the testing goat](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book-upgraded-to-django-17.html) too (It is updated for django 1.7).